# How do I dump the SSL certificate when using a HTTP proxy?

Tags: ssl, curl, proxy

The classic was of dumping a certificate with `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect HOST:443` does not work if you want to debug a https_proxy based connection.

Assuming that `https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:3128` how can I dump the certificate returned by the *proxy* when making a http request to, lets say `https://pypi.org`

Clearly the returned certificate is supposed to created on the fly by the proxy using its own CA authority.

I want to dump this certificate because while curl accepts it as valid without any problems I found that python-requests chokes.

Comment: In [openssl 1.1.0 and later](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-s_client.html) there is a `-proxy` option to `s_client`. Other then that it is unclear what tools you have available apart from `openssl`. For example it could be done with small scripts in Perl or Python, one could do a packet capture and extract the certificate with Wireshark and probably others. Note also that none of this gives you what you likely really need to have - which is the root CA at the proxy which has issued the new certificate. You only get the newly issued certificate and maybe some chain certs.